# Linking library with gcc - ld: cannot find -larpack

Tags: c++, gcc, installation, arpack

I am installing software on a server with no root privileges. I come across the following error during installation:

```
make[1]: *** [hgaprec] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/seq/.../SOFTWARE/hgaprec/src'
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
Making install in src
make[1]: Entering directory `/seq/.../SOFTWARE/hgaprec/src'
g++  -O3   -o hgaprec ratings.o main.o log.o hgaprec.o -larpack -llapack -
lblas -lgsl -lpthread -lgslcblas 
/.../software/free/Linux/redhat_6_x86_64/pkgs/gcc_5.2.0/bin/ld: cannot 
find -larpack
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [hgaprec] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/seq/.../SOFTWARE/hgaprec/src'
make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
```

Since library arpack could not be found, I then installed it here /seq/.../SOFTWARE/hgaprec/ARPACK and found that the process generated a static file libarpack_LINUX.a. To link this static library to gcc the following command was used:

```
gcc -larpack -L/seq/.../SOFTWARE/hgaprec/ARPACK/libarpack_LINUX.a
```

However, I keep getting the same error while installation of the software that larpack was not found. Am I using the linking command wrong?

Comment: A nice trick is to run `gcc -m64 -W,verbose ...` which should tell the linker to display exactly where it's looking

Comment: Don't put the name of the library after -L, just the directory it's in. I don't know if it matters, but you should just put the directory. If I'm linking against libA.a, for example, I would type: ```gcc main.c -L/path/to/lib -lA```

Comment: So you should try ```gcc main.c -L/path/to/lib -larpack_LINUX```

Comment: Why do you have the `..` after `/seq`, are you abbreviating a long path? If it's literal, `/seq/../SOFTWARE/hgaprec/ARPACK/` is equivalent to `/SOFTWARE/hgaprec/ARPACK`.

Comment: Using abbreviation as the path is too long

Comment: Also, are you sure it is in ```/seq/otherstuff```? Or is it installed relative to where you are at ```seq/otherstuff?```Is it an absolute or relative path?

Comment: Like dlasalle says, in this context '..' has special meaning, so if you mean an abbreviation, use '..;' or something else altogether.

Answer (score 1):

You either want `gcc main.c /seq/../SOFTWARE/hgaprec/ARPACK/libarpack_LINUX.a` (you don't need `-l` and `-L` if you're specifying the full path to static library), or as @Julian_Cienfuegos suggested `gcc main.c -L/seq/../SOFTWARE/hgaprec/ARPACK/ -larpack_LINUX`. This assumes you're only compiling a single file called `main.c` which contains your `main()` function, and outputs the `a.out` binary.

EDIT: Added explanation of `main.c`.

Comment: Could you please expand on <file.c>? Is this a necessary argument? I don't see a main.c in arpack or hgaprec

Answer (score 0):

My issue got solved after including the ARPACK library path as part of LD flag in configure like so:

./configure --prefix=/seq/.../SOFTWARE/hgaprec LDFLAGS="-L/seq/.../SOFTWARE/hgaprec/ARPACK/"